# Adempiere setup blocked due to improper JDK

Tags: java, adempiere

I am trying to install Adempiere. I have already tried to change the environment variables but unable to install due to an error in the JDK version. How do i resolve it?

Comment: What's the error you got? And which JDK version did you use?

Comment: incomplete question, please provide more information

Answer (score 1):

The latest version (3.9.0) of ADempiere is compatible with JDK version 8.  Detailed installation instructions are available in the ADempiere docs at http://wiki.adempiere.net.

For installation issues, consider joining the ADempiere community chat at http://www.adempiere.net/web/guest/chat-on-line.  It is a better forum for application specific questions.